# Debouncer in Polymer 3.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

How to properly write debouncer in Polymer 3 ?

According to [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/api/utils/debounce)

> ```
> import {microTask} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/async.js';
> import {Debouncer} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/debounce.js';
> // ...
>
> _debounceWork() {
>   this._debounceJob = Debouncer.debounce(this._debounceJob,
>       microTask, () => this._doWork());
> }
> ```

This is nice, but I need to configure some timing. For example, this is how I have been doing it in Polymer 1

```
  this.debounce("scroll",function() {
      this.$$("#scrollThreshold").clearTriggers();
  }.bind(this), 400);
```

and Polymer 2

```
this._debouncer = Polymer.Debouncer.debounce(
    this._debouncer, // initially undefined
    Polymer.Async.timeOut.after(400),
    () => {
       // some code
    }
);
```

but I have no idea how to set 400ms debounce in Polymer 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `async` module has the `timeout` function but you need to import it

```
import {timeOut} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/async.js';

this._debouncer = Debouncer.debounce(
    this._debouncer, // initially undefined
    timeOut.after(400),
    () => {
       // some code
    }
);
```